# How to read a DBML file and map it into an object model in .NET?

Tags: linq, code-generation, object-model, sqlmetal

I'm planning to write a code generator to generate UI (forms, grids, etc.). Since I'm using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) I'm planning to read a DBML file for metadata extraction purposes. Is there some API to read the DBML object model (database, tables, columns, and associations)?

I've opened `SQLMetal.exe` with [Red Gate Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Gate_Software)'s [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector). It contains a namespace called `LinqToSqlShared.DbmlObjectModel` and it seems it contains everything I need to read a DBML object model. The bad news is: that namespace is not exposed for external consumption and all classes are declared as "Friend" (or sealed).

Once again, does something exist, like the `LinqToSqlShared.DbmlObjectModel` namespace, to read DBML to an object model in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).? Or do I have to write it my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how the model is read in [L2ST4](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) project. You could reuse the [T4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit) file.

Comment: Excelent!, this is exactly what i wanted to do.

The class Data does the fantastic job for me. However implementation in a .tt file requires some human interaction, what i really want is to create a command line tool to generate classes and even user interfaces in an automated way.  

For now i've isolated the [Data] class in a dll to work in vb.net (wich is the language i am familiar with ;) )

i will let you know how it goes. thanks for such a fantastic piece of code. you save several weeks of work. 

i owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a tool like [Reegenerator](http://www.reegenerator.com/). We're considering this as a replacement for the L2S code generator, because we've got some specific code generation requirements.

Comment: I've seen the tool you talk about, i've seen the video and it seems pretty interesting. 
However i will use T4 templates for code generation wich is pretty easy to implement and create customized code.  The only thing i need is to extract object model from dbml file.